# Using href="tel:XXXXX" in links for contact numbers on web pages

Tags: html, mobile

Would it be recommended to use href="tel:XXXXXX" for contact telephone numbers on web pages?

I appreciate that this can benefit mobile users when they access your site but are there any potential pitfalls, such as spam calls? 
Is there a best practice method that could be used that will benefit the user and website owner?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Regards

Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this for over a year now on my homepage and didn't get any spam calls. It could irritate users with desktop-browsers if you display the link as any other link, though.

Comment: Good to know you haven't had any trouble using it so far, hope it doesn't become a problem in the future as it looks very useful for mobile users. Will probably implement it and see how it pans out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hyperlinking the telephone number itself, how about placing a small phone icon next to the number and hyperlinking *it* instead.

Comment: Any spambot looking for tel links is going to be looking at the HTML for `href="tel:` though.

Comment: As @ceejayoz would still have a problem if spambots start to pick up on this, if they haven't already.